# How to call files present in private folder in PHP

Tags: php

My web files are present under

> D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\http\

I can call the files inside my any of web files from above directory like

> website.com\index.php etc...

Now I want to place a file in private folder for security reasons especially to save passwords

> D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private\test.ini

i want use this test.ini file in following function
parse_ini_file("**< path >**test.ini")

> what should be the value of < path > ?

when I use *D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.org\private\test.ini* it says
**Warning: parse_ini_file(D:\inetpubhosts\website.com\private est.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream:**

Comment: #1. Value of path is `D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private\`.  #2. You can save config files in test.php, and put variables in array or constants, so no need for parsing ini files, just include.

Comment: Eeeeewwww, your using IIS.

Comment: @Glavić : D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private is throwing error

Comment: Then the path is not correct or you have permission problems.

Comment: @Glavić: as i said, it is private can not be accessed through http

Comment: If you wish to access files with php, then php/apache/iis must have permissions to that folder; simple as that...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you know that your `private` folder will be one directory level above, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
define ('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);               // So we don't have to type DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR...
define ('ROOT_DIRECTORY', dirname(__FILE__));
define ('PRIVATE_DIRECTORY', ROOT_DIRECTORY . DS . 'private');
```

Now you can just do stuff like this:

```
<?php
$parsed = parse_ini_file (PRIVATE_DIRECTORY . DS . 'my_ini_file.ini');

// or
require_once PRIVATE_DIRECTORY . DS . 'myfile.php';
```

Note: this is also system-independant as it will work on both Windows and *nix systems with no problem.

You can find more information in the PHP manual: [**dirname()**](https://www.php.net/dirname), [**DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR**](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) and [******FILE******](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

EDIT:

If the root folder will be more than one level above in the directory structure you can always do this:

```
<?php
// If the directory in which this file is located is: D:\inetpub\foo\bar\baz\file.php
// and the root directory is D:\inetpub\foo 
// Then you can do the followwing
define ('ROOT_DIRECTORY', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));

// dirname ("D:\inetpub\foo\bar\baz\file.php");    // D:\inetpub\foo\bar\baz
// dirname ("D:\inetpub\foo\bar\baz");             // D:\inetpub\foo\bar
// dirname ("D:\inetpub\foo\bar");                 // D:\inetpub\foo
```

Its all about defining your `ROOT` directory and use that as a reference for defining/including everything else.

Hope this helps

Comment: it may be more than one directory level above.. How to call the file if i am at D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\http\test\ 
and call D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private\test.ini

Comment: Just add more calls to `dirname()`. I'll make an example in an edit.

Comment: still says, Warning: parse_ini_file(D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\httpdocs\test\private\test.ini)
i want the value to be D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private\test.ini
and i am running the page from D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\httpdocs\test\sample.php

Comment: Try to use   define ('ROOT_DIRECTORY', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

Comment: If you have your sample.php file in `D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\httpdocs\test\sample.php` then thats `define('ROOT_DIRECTORY', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));` to get the root folder which is `D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com`.

Comment: @vanneto : now fine with the path.. its picking when i use multiple dirname() ; But i have permission issue to that private folder. If i have read permission, will it be accessible to 3rd parties ?

Comment: PHP will be able to access it. But its the server (in your case IIS) that controls what will be accessible to the public. For example, if you set up your server to serve files only from the `http` folder then you should be fine, PHP will be still able to access files outside of the `http` folder.

Answer (score 1):

For

D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\http\index.php

```
<?php

print_r( parse_ini_file('../private/test.ini') );
```

To Access

D:\inetpub\vhosts\website.com\private\test.ini

PHP will automaticly convert unix style dir name seperator (/ insted of ) to windows style, this makes some things easyer.

If you like to be independ of includep path and cwd, use.
Work since php 5.3

```
<?php

print_r( parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/../private/test.ini') );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: It throws error
Warning: parse_ini_file(__DIR__/../private/test.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: dont remote the qutes. and check above if tbe pathes are like im written.

Comment: i have just copy pasted whatever you have typed. it shows 
Warning: parse_ini_file(__DIR__/../private/test.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory